# How to get the updated or latest value of a selected value in React

Tags: reactjs, select, setstate

I have a select option with values where I select items. Next to the select dropdown I have a button to add this selected item in the dropdown to a list. I have a state variable where I store the selected item value with setState. And the Idea is to use this statea variable's value when clicking on a button.

```
<select onChange={this.getSelectedValue}>
    <option value="item1"> Item 1 </option>
       ---- omitted for brevity 
</select>
<button onClick={this.onAddToList} > Add to List </button>





// my function
getSelectedValue= (e) => {
     setState({item: e.target.value })
}

 // my function to be called on Click event of a button 
onAddToList()
{
   // Here this.state.item is either null or will have previously selected item from the list. I know setState is async but how to get the right selected value from the dropdown ?
 var itemSelected = this.state.item;
 ....rest of the code
  }
```

The problem: I can not get the exact selected value of the dropdown on the click event handler - onAddToList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to re-produce your case. Everything is fine but i have some notices:

- When you dont init variable item of your state. If you click `Add to List`. You will get `undefinded`. Because, You have not change option yet.
- You may use class component. So, setState should be `this.setState({item: e.target.value })`.
- You also should bind `this` for function handles. If you have not done in constructor yet. `this.getSelectedValue.bind(this)` and `this.onAddToList.bind(this)`